# 3D texture coordinates for a cube

Tags: opengl, textures, opengl-3

I want to use glTexImage3D with cube. what will be the texture coordinates for it? i am using GL_TEXTURE_3D as target.
I tried with u v coordinates same as 2d texture coordinates with z component 0-depth for each face. But that goes wrong.

These are the texture coordinates i was using which seems to be incorrect.

```
        GLfloat texcoords[]={

        0.0, 0.0,0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,1.0,
        0.0, 1.0,0.0,

        0.0, 0.0,0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,1.0,
        0.0, 1.0,0.0,

        0.0, 0.0,0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,1.0,
        0.0, 1.0,0.0,

        0.0, 0.0,0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,1.0,
        0.0, 1.0,0.0,

        0.0, 0.0,0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,1.0,
        0.0, 1.0,0.0,

        0.0, 0.0,0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,1.0,
        0.0, 1.0,0.0
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not want to use a 3D texture just for texturing the faces of a cube. More likely you want to use a *cube map* – essentially a set of 6 2D textures one for each face of a cube – which by its very nature nicely matches the topology of a cube.

Comment: @datewolf: I know about cub maps in 2D texture, but i want to use specifically 3D texture only. Let me know how to do that.

Comment: @Roshan: The problem is, that a 3D texture is effectively a volume of texels that are interpolated in all directions. Hence if you use the r (=depth) coordinate for adjacent faces some weird interpolation artifacts will show up. If you want to give each face a different r coordinate use a GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, which does no interpolation between layers.

Comment: is it possible to use glTexImage3D with target GL_TEXTURE_3D to apply on cube?

Comment: @Roshan: Well sure it is, but it will surely not do what you expect. Imagine that 3d texture being a solid block of wood out of which you carve some cube. You see only the faces of the cube, and where through the texture they slice. But there's a large amount of texture "inside" which you don't see. 3D textures have two main domains: Rendering of volumetric data (in a volume raycaster) or as a 3D lookup table. *A 3D texture is not the right thing to texture a cube with. Yes it can be done but it's not very sensible.*

Comment: I agree with you but i am just implementing a some scenario as per documentation :)

Comment: @Roshan: Well you can use a say 128×128×6 3D texture and assign each face of the cube a different depth texture coordinate; if you use separated vertices this should work if you hit the layer straight on and there's no mip mapping. Otherwise you'll get interesting interpolation effects.

Comment: Yeah, I previosly was trying to use 8*8*6 3D texture but because of incorrect texture coordinate i was getting some weird output. Hence the question :) I am adding the coordinates i was using. Please let me know whats wrong in those.

Comment: @Roshan: I'm going to edit my answer, but before I do I suggest you take a piece of paper and sketch out the surfaces in 3D texture space (assume the texture coordinated to form a 3D cartesian space) you're assigning there. Maybe you see your mistake then.

Comment: These coordinates work perfectly for glteximage3D but when i use texsubimage3D it does not replace the texels correctly the reason of which i thought is texture coordinates.

Comment: @Roshan: Could you please show both your call to glTexImage3D and glTexSubImage3D. There should be no difference in rendering if the same data is supplied through them.